# XQuery methods on CAST as XML, exist() returns 0

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

Querying to sql server 2008, I have a table with a column storing xmldata as text, lets say:

```
TABLE(identifier varchar(15), xmldata text)
```

That xml looks a little like this (note, there is no explicit root element)

```
<notRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns = "tons.o/NDA/HIPAA/" attribute_1 = "value_1" ... attribute_n = "value_n" >
    <node nAttribute1 = "41pha0000" nAttribute2 = "VALUE" />
</notRoot>
```

-exactly 1 notRoot, and exactly 1 node per row stored in the db
-trying to access the node attribute values
-this will run nigh for eternity, and will hurt immensely trying to substring it
-(xml is going to be text in other places, I need to know how to do this in the future)

So, in order to grab it and have that node accessible as xml (ideally, otherwise I'm going to have to linq in or something to make this portable), I cast as xml, and try to use the different XQuery methods on the cast value. I've included the various behaviors I've observed with my failures:

```
select top 1 
 (CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).query('.')             --returns the whole shebang
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('.')             --returns 1
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('(.)[0]')        -- 0, as mentioned below, XML isn't 0 indexed
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('(.)[1]')        -- 1, so this exists
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('/notRoot')      -- 0
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('//notRoot')     -- 0 (sorry ZLK, it was a good idea)
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('/notRoot/node') -- 0
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('(/notRoot)[0]') -- 0, as expected
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('(/notRoot)[1]') -- 0, unfortunate
,(CAST(l.xmldata as xml)).exist('(//notRoot)[1]')-- 0, ditto
from database.dbo.log l
```

Is it that there's no root element?
Does it have to be stored in an xml typed variable to do it with this XQuery(modeled after the MSDN reference for the different methods)? 
Can anyone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: OK. A couple things here. First, XML indexes start at 1, not 0. So the element at index 0 should never exist (you see this with your 3rd/4th selects). Second, I'm guessing your `notRoot` element is either inside another element (e.g. `<z><notRoot...`) or you're not using correct case (e.g. it's written `notroot` in your column). If your notRoot is in a tree of elements, you won't find it by checking if it exists like you're currently doing. You can add another / (e.g. `exist('//notRoot')`, which will search the entire xml for that element.

Comment: By the way, here's one way you might query your table if you know there's only one instance of `notRoot` in the XML: `SELECT a.b.query('.') FROM (SELECT identifier, xmldata = CAST(xmldata AS XML) FROM database.dbo.log) l CROSS APPLY l.xmldata.nodes('//notRoot') AS a(b);`

Comment: There are several flaws in your approach... Please provide a sample of your XML with realistic data and what output you want to get from there. Why do you need *that node accessible as xml (ideally)*? Might be a misunderstanding and you just want to say, that you want to read via XML methods rather than string parsing? Important questions: Is there one element or might be *more-of-the-same*? Are there many attributes in `<notRoot>`? Does `n_attribute` point to *many of them*? Are the attributes always the same?

Answer (score 1):

As a start off:

- `TEXT` has been deprecated for more than 15 years now. Future versions won't support it anymore
- If you have to deal with XML you should store it in a column of type `XML`. Really, if you can change this, than do it!
- Placing questions about SQL and XML on SO should always be accompained by a realistic example. Something like `<node n_attributes = "n_values" ...>` might be clear for you, but not for an external. Please read the questions in my comment below your question and provide further details!

I just asked my magic crystall ball and it told me, that you might be looking for something like this:

**Assumptions**

- There are many `<notRoot>` elements within one entry
- no actual `<root>` element
- attribute names are the same in all nodes
- no namespaces
- only one `<node>` per `<notRoot>`

Try this:

--A declared dummy table to *mock-up* your scenario

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(identifier varchar(15), xmldata text);
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES
('record 1','<notRoot nr_a1 = "nr1_v1" nr_a2="nr1_v2">
                <node n1= "v1" n2="v2" n3="v3"/>
             </notRoot>
             <notRoot nr_a1 = "nr2_v1" nr_a2="nr2_v2">
                <node n1= "a" n2="b" n3="c"/>
             </notRoot>')
,('record 2','<notRoot nr_a1 = "one more" nr_a2="xyz">
                <node n1= "1" n2="2" n3="3"/>
             </notRoot>
             <notRoot nr_a1 = "and even more" nr_a2="more more more">
                <node n1= "100" n2="200" n3="300"/>
             </notRoot>');
WITH Casted AS
(            
    SELECT t.identifier
          ,CAST(t.xmldata AS XML) AS TheXml
    FROM @dummy AS t
)
```

--the query

```
SELECT c.identifier
      ,c.TheXml
      ,nr.value(N'@nr_a1',N'nvarchar(max)') AS notRoot_a1
      ,nr.value(N'@nr_a2',N'nvarchar(max)') AS notRoot_a2
      ,nr.value(N'(node/@n1)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS node_n1
      ,nr.value(N'(node/@n2)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS node_n2
      ,nr.value(N'(node/@n3)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS node_n3
FROM Casted AS c
OUTER APPLY c.TheXml.nodes(N'//notRoot') AS A(nr)
```

The result:

```
identifier  notRoot_a1  notRoot_a2       node_n1    node_n2 node_n3
record 1    nr1_v1          nr1_v2          v1      v2       v3
record 1    nr2_v1          nr2_v2          a       b        c
record 2    one more        xyz             1       2        3
record 2    and even more   more more more  100     200      300
```

### UPDATE

According to your edit there is a default namespace, which either must be declared or wildcarded (`*:elementname`).

Further more your edit looks like you do not know the number of attributes nor their names in advance. As there might be n attributes in `<notRoot>` **and** n attributes in `<node>` you'll get an *each-with-each* result. Might be better to place two different calls.

If you know the names of the attributes in advance (even if not all of them are used by all XMLs, it would be much easier...

Try this:

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(identifier varchar(15), xmldata text);
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES
('record 1','<notRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns = "tons.o/NDA/HIPAA/" 
              attribute_1 = "value_1" attribute_n = "value_n" >
                  <node nAttribute1 = "41pha0000" nAttribute2 = "VALUE" />
             </notRoot>
             <notRoot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns = "tons.o/NDA/HIPAA/" 
              attribute_1 = "other" attribute_n = "other_n" >
                  <node nAttribute1 = "xyz" nAttribute2 = "blah" />
             </notRoot>');


WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'tons.o/NDA/HIPAA/') 
,Casted AS
(            
    SELECT t.identifier
          ,CAST(t.xmldata AS XML) AS TheXml
    FROM @dummy AS t
)
--the query

SELECT Casted.identifier
      ,nrAttr.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS notRoot_attr_name
      ,nrAttr.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)') AS notRoot_attr
      ,ndAttr.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS notRoot_attr_name
      ,ndAttr.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)') AS notRoot_attr
FROM Casted
OUTER APPLY Casted.TheXml.nodes(N'/notRoot/@*') AS A(nr)
OUTER APPLY nr.nodes(N'@*') AS B(nrAttr)
OUTER APPLY nr.nodes(N'node') AS C(nd)
OUTER APPLY nd.nodes(N'@*') AS D(ndAttr)
```

The result

```
record 1    attribute_1 value_1 nAttribute1 41pha0000
record 1    attribute_1 value_1 nAttribute2 VALUE
record 1    attribute_n value_n nAttribute1 41pha0000
record 1    attribute_n value_n nAttribute2 VALUE
record 1    attribute_1 other   nAttribute1 xyz
record 1    attribute_1 other   nAttribute2 blah
record 1    attribute_n other_n nAttribute1 xyz
record 1    attribute_n other_n nAttribute2 blah
```

Comment: -I've brought up the whole TEXT issue, as has our resident wizard. It is what it is.  
-data is closer now, but I have to be incredibly careful  
-gave most of what you suggested a shot, but it's still returning null on the value() calls  
-but it got the ctes to work, so that's already a help

Comment: @RyanWood *still returning null* is bound to the namespaces... The default namespace is declared with `xmlns="SomeName"`. You might let it away and use a wildcard instead `*:element`. Hope this helps...

Comment: @RyanWood Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Did you find my last update?

Comment: sorry about the delay, SLA crunch.
using default namespace:

XQuery [A.msg.nodes()]: There is no attribute named '@*' in the type 'attribute(*,xdt:untypedAtomic)'.

I also tried using the name. No dice.
 wildcards returned null, xnmlnamespace (N'blah' as x) ... value(N'(/x:notRoot)[1],N'varchar(max)')  -> null... oh man this is getting depressing

Comment: I do know the names of the attributes of node though, and for our case, there will only be 2, and we can scrap the notRoot attributes of that makes it any easier. You're already a saint from my perspective